# serverspec if statement for mysql version on server

Tags: mysql, testing, automated-testing, serverspec

Is there a way to check which package installed on server by command output?

```ruby
describe command('mysql -e "select version();"') do
  if its(:stdout) { should =~ /5.6.27-76.0-log/ } 
    describe package('MySQL-client') do
    it { should be_installed }
  else
    describe package('Percona-client') do
    it { should be_installed }
  end
end
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I could not invent a way better then this:

```ruby
def mysql_version
  command('mysql -e "select version();"').stdout
end

def plain_mysql?
  mysql_version =~ /5.6.27-76.0-log/
end

def mysql_package_name
  if plain_mysql?
    'MySQL-client'
  else
    'Percona-client'
  end
end

describe package(mysql_package_name) do
  it { should be_installed }
end
```